# Gauss-Seidel vs Jacobi Convergence

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

I am trying to prove why Ax=b where
$$
A= \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 1\\
    -1 & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & 2 & -3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
b= \begin{bmatrix}
   0\\0\\0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
converges for Jacobi and does not converge for Gauss-Seidel. So far, I found that the spectral radius for the Jacobi iteration matrix is less than 1 and that the matrix is diagonally dominant. However, for the Gauss-Seidel method I am having a harder time understanding where to start. I was thinking of finding the spectral radius of the iteration matrix $-(D+L)^{-1}*U$, but I don't know if this the correct formula as it was one I found in a random online source and I do not see it in my class textbook. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I would imagine you have to have a solution vector (RHS) values for each row. Unless you are after just a matrix inverse.

Comment: The formula is correct. For convergence, you have to look at the spectral radius. If the spectral radius is less than $1$, you get convergence. If it is larger than $1$, you get divergence. If it is exactly one, you have to find some argument yourself, whether it converges, diverges. This might be different for different first iterates.

Comment: yes I believe so, It seems very similar to what I did. Thank you

Comment: @user1106787 Your answer needs some clarification... I suppose you want to establish convergence, regardless of the initial approximation, but you do not explicitly say so. Note that if you take as initial approximation $x^{(0)} = 0$, both methods converge.

Comment: @PierreCarre, the initial guess is (1,1,1), I saw that the solutions bounced around between -1,-1,-1 and 1,1,1. Is there a different way without the spectral radius to show why this diverges or do we use the spectral radius in conjunction with the initial guess